# Debian 8 + Foreman Not Loading

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

I'm working on giving foreman a try, I installed it on Debian 8 per the tutorial on the site.  However, when I try to load foreman I get:

Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.

```
# in usr/share/foreman-proxy/modules/root/root_api.rb
class Proxy::RootApi
  get '/' do
    "Hello World"
  end
end
```

I'm not seeing anything useful in the production log either.  Any suggestions?  Is there a different log I should be looking at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main services when installing Foreman - one is Foreman (installed on port 80/http, and 443/https), and the other is the Foreman/Smart Proxy (installed on port 8443). The smart proxy is an API for managing services such as DHCP, Puppet etc, and isn't intended to be used directly in a web browser.

The message you're getting sounds like you're accessing the smart proxy, so instead access the regular port 80 or 443: https://foreman.example.com/